# How to type event on scroll handler react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll

I have a page with lazy loading. There is a scroll listener inside it. I need to type event in the scrollHandler function.

```
const scrollHandler = (e: any) => {
        let scrollHeight = e.target.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        let scrollTop = e.target.documentElement.scrollTop;
        let innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
        if (scrollHeight - (scrollTop + innerHeight) < 100) {
            dispatch(setStatus(Status.LOADING));
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
        return function () {
            document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
        }
    });
```

I tried Event type. It returns me this error:

> TS2339: Property 'documentElement' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convince TypeScript that the element you're referring to is indeed a Document element. You can do that this way:

```
const target = e.target;
if (!(target instanceof Document)) return;
```

For the lines that come later, TS would know that `target` is a Document element and should have a property named `documentElement`.